# Share custom taxonomy between "custom post type" and "users"

Tags: wordpress

I want to have a custom taxonomy named skills.
So, i want assign this taxonomy between project custom post type and users.
I means, i can select skills taxonomy in project custom post type (**no problem**)
and i can select skills taxonomy in user profile ( **main problem** )
Can anyone help me ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no core implementation of `'tax_query'` in `WP_User_Query` yet.

Nevertheless there is an alternative way using `get_objects_in_term`

```
$taxonomy = 'skills';
$users = get_objects_in_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );    

if(!empty($users)){

    // WP_User_Query arguments
    $args = array (
        'role'           => 'teacher',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'orderby'        => 'user_registered',
        'include'        => $users
    );

    // The User Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    // The User Loop
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
            echo '<li><span>' . esc_html( $user->skill ) . '</span></li>';
        }
    } 
    else {
        // number of found 
    }
}
else {
    // no users found
}
```

OR If you want to add taxonomy for both section and users please use this below code.

Pass post type as per your requirement and user also

function my_register_user_taxonomy() {

```
 register_taxonomy(
    'profession',
    'user',
    array(
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Professions' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Profession' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Professions' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Professions' ),
            'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Professions' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Professions' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Profession' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Profession' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Profession' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Profession Name' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate professions with commas' ),
            'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove professions' ),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most popular professions' ),
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => true,
            'slug' => 'author/profession' // Use 'author' (default WP user slug).
        ),
        'capabilities' => array(
            'manage_terms' => 'edit_users', // Using 'edit_users' cap to keep this simple.
            'edit_terms'   => 'edit_users',
            'delete_terms' => 'edit_users',
            'assign_terms' => 'read',
        ),
        'update_count_callback' => 'my_update_profession_count' // Use a custom function to update the count.
    )
);
```

}